# Strange switch operator behaviour

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Good day all,

I am really struggling to give the post proper heading (describing the problem), so please forgive me.

**Problem:**

I have the class with two methods as follows:

```
1  import FormPopulator = require("../util/FormPopulator");
2 
3  class UIX {
4    
5     formPopulator: FormPopulator;
6 
7     contructor () {
8         this.formPopulator = new FormPopulator();
9     }
10     
11    public setDefaultValues(defaultValues: DefaultValues) {
12        for (var i = 0; i < SearchAllFormProperties.searchFormProperties.length; i++) {
13            this.pushDataToUI(SearchAllFormProperties.searchFormProperties[i], defaultValues);
14        }
15        alert("End Of the loop.");
16    }
17 
18    public pushDataToUI(property: string, defaultValues: DefaultValues) {
19        switch (property) {
20            case "textField": 
21                (<HTMLInputElement> document.getElementById("textField")).value = "";
22                break;
23            case "dropDown":
24                this.formPopulator.populateTheDropBox("dropDown", defaultValues.listOfValues);
25                alert("after populateTheDropBox");  
26                break;
27            default:
28                alert("Property: " + property + " is not accepted.");
29        }
30     }
31  }
```

**Now** - `setDefaultValues` is called, but the execution doesn't get to line `15` of class **UIX**, unless I comment out line `24` of a same class i.e. `populateTheDropBox` call, however it gets to line `25` meaning it returned from `populateTheDropBox` method, but why doesn't it go back to `setDefaultValues` ?

```
1  class FormPopulator {
2      public populateTheDropBox(selectElementID: string, listOfElements: Array<any>) {
3 
4          // Get the combo box
5          var selectElement = <HTMLSelectElement> document.getElementById(comboBoxID);
6          // Reset the options 
7          selectElement.options.length = 0;
8
9          for (var i = 0; i < listOfElements.length; i++) {
10      
11             var option = document.createElement("option");
12             option.value = ""+listOfElements[i].id;
13             option.innerHTML = listOfElements[i].value;
14      
15             selectElement.appendChild(option);
16         }
17      }   
18  }
```

**P.S.** If I comment out the loop starting at line `9` of class **FormPopulator** - it return back to `setDefaultValues` and executes line `15` of class **UIX** i.e. `alert("End Of the loop.");`

I am really struggling to explain this behaviour and there is no exceptions.

Comment: It sounds like unhandled exception. If using Chrome to debug - make sure you have "Pause on Caught Exceptions" set to true. Just in case you might already handle it somewhere upper in the call stack.

Comment: The only logical explanation I can find is that somehow `populateTheDropBox` increases `SearchAllFormProperties.searchFormProperties.length` and causes the loop to run forever...

Comment: Aviad - No, I've printed the index value - it is correct and the loop ends.

Comment: Amid - Will do that. I have the working solution by avoiding the loop and duplicating some code, but this bugs me.

Comment: The loop ends and the `alert` isn't executed? -- Try a `console.log` instead see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

> unless I comment out line 24 of a same class i.e. populateTheDropBox call, however it gets to line 25 meaning it returned from populateTheDropBox method, but why doesn't it go back to setDefaultValues

Based on your code you are calling `pushDataToUI` in a loop. Just because you get to line 25 `alert("after populateTheDropBox");` **once** doesn't mean the loop is terminated. It might continue to execute (and probably has a javascript error at some point that crashes the call stack) and you might never get to `alert("End Of the loop.");`.